# AJAX image upload possible jquery with preview

Tags: php, ajax, file-upload, asyncfileupload

I am trying to find some sort of plug-in for Ajax upload with a file preview. The image will be saved into a MySQL dataBase. Is that even possible? I guess all things are possible with certain requirements. Have you guys ever come across anything like that?

Comment: don't save the image file content into database just save the path/name of the image in the database

Comment: That sounds like a good idea, But I am going to have to figure out where I store all those images once there uploaded.

Comment: use a descriptive path & name for the images, there are many many ways to store them, ex: using directory called by the current date

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also store the uploaded images in a directory and their names in the database.

I have developed a jQuery plugin that performs a dynamic upload of an image when it is selected, and previews it.

You can find a demo of the UploaderPreviewer plugin here:

http://dondedeportes.es/uploader-previewer

Hope it is useful for you or for anyone with the same problem.

Answer (score 5):

*Let me tackle your question one bit at a time:*

**I am trying to find some sort of plug-in for Ajax upload...**

[BAM!](http://blog.insicdesigns.com/2010/02/10-best-ajax-file-uploader-for-your-web-application/)

**...with a file preview.**

[Yep, from the page above](http://webdeveloperplus.com/jquery/ajax-multiple-file-upload-form-using-jquery/), although I might wonder why this is necessary and if it isn't remove it (I believe minimalist design is usually better) and go with [fancy upload](http://digitarald.de/project/fancyupload/3-0/showcase/photoqueue/) which seems to be more popular (sorry, I don't have much experience with ajax uploaders)

**The image will be saved into a MySQL dataBase. Is that even possible?**

Unfortunately, it is; you will have to use the [blob data type](http://www.mwasif.com/2007/4/save-image-in-mysql-with-php/) ([alternate tutorial](http://forum.codecall.net/php-tutorials/6937-tutorial-storing-images-mysql-php.html)). Personally though I would just create a directory and save the images there, because then you don't have to query MySQL every f***ing time you want to display the image (I would feel bad for hat server). In which case I suggest you use [class.upload.php](http://www.verot.net/php_class_upload.htm) (I have good experiences with it), in conjunction with whatever ajax uploader you chose to use.

**I guess all things are possible with certain requirements. Have you guys ever come across anything like that?**

...yes

Comment: That sir is a thorough answer of a question.  Uploading to a directory and not mysql sounds like a good idea, and I initially wanted to go in that direction, but the people I work with insist on uploading pics directly to mysql (ugh!!!!) maybe I can convince them.

Comment: Your welcome; I would definitely try to convince them to use a directory instead of a blob because the server load caused from a constant mysql query and base64 decrypt is a real concern.

Comment: One thing I notice, these all seem really complicated?  I wouldn't think it would take so much code just to upload a file.